# How Can I float a log in and sign up link or button to the right of the page?

Tags: alignment, floating

I am trying to float the log in and sign up buttons for a webpage to the right of the title of the page. Basically:

"Welcome to my Webpage!!!"                                                        "Log In" "Sign Up"

I've tried css float properties and align properties but can't get anything to work.